# Resolving conflict between variables between main loop and playa:parents loop

Tags: playa, custom-fields

Playa experts out there: I thought variable prefix parameter would solve this one, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding how it's intended to be used.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
{exp:channel:entries set="prod" dynamic="no" disable="pagination"}
<li class="{if segment_1 == url_title} active{/if} has-dropdown"><a href="{path='{url_title}'}">{title}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="{path='{PROD_CHANNEL_url_title}/docs'}">API Docs</a>
{exp:playa:parents channel="api" field="cf_apis_related_product"}
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="{path='{PROD_CHANNEL_url_title}/docs/{API_CHANNEL_url_title}'}">{title}</a></li>
</ul>
{/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is there a namespacing way to get the url title from within the wrapping entries loop WITHIN the playa parents loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `var_prefix=""` parameter is for. Update your code like this.

```
{exp:channel:entries set="prod" dynamic="no" disable="pagination"}
...
    {exp:playa:parents channel="api" field="cf_apis_related_product" var_prefix="api"}
    <ul class="dropdown">
         <li><a href="{path='{PROD_CHANNEL_url_title}/docs/{api:url_title}'}">{api:title}</a></li>
    </ul>
    {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Ahhhh. You are the man, Jeremy. Thank you for setting me straight on that. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Sure thing. Glad to help.